# Проблема с сессией PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, проблема с сессией PHP:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Winginx\home\wc.loc\public_html\admin\index.php:1) in C:\Winginx\home\wc.loc\public_html\protect.php on line 2 Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\Winginx\home\wc.loc\public_html\admin\index.php:1) in C:\Winginx\home\wc.loc\public_html\protect.php on line 2 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Winginx\home\wc.loc\public_html\admin\index.php:1) in C:\Winginx\home\wc.loc\public_html\protect.php on line 3

Кодировка UTF-8 без BOM стоит, ничего перед стартом сессии нет. 
Вот начало кода самого index.php:

```
<?php
require_once('../protect.php');
require_once('../database.php');
$sql_connection = dbConnect();
```

Файл protect.php(также UTF-8 без BOM), в нём начало:

```
session_start();
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
require_once('database.php');
```

Причём, проект этот делал довольно давно, и тогда всё работало, да и на хостинге также работало без проблем.

Версия PHP: 5.3.27.

Comment: он говорит что session_start это третья строка файла, protect.php какие 2 предыдущие ?

Comment: @Mike, первой строкой лишь <?php и всё, дальше старт сессии. Прилагаю скриншот http://i.imgur.com/luPis4p.jpg

Comment: "Кодировка UTF-8 без BOM стоит" - проверьте еще раз в hex-редакторе. Обратите внимание на "output started at C:\Winginx\home\wc.loc\public_html\admin\index.php:1" - это строка `<?php` - перед ней наверняка BOM

Comment: @tutankhamun, и в правду! Что-то редактор подвёл, или я не доглядел. Спасибо Вам, а то уже на что только не грешил :)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно есть невидимые символы в вашем редакторе. Открой через другой редактор. Или лучше всего переименуй текущий файл создай полностью новый файл и скопируй в него содержимое. По идее редактор не будет копировать символы которые не выводит.